# Don't add var when compiling Coffeescript

Tags: javascript, node.js, inheritance, coffeescript

I'm writing a simple app that uses [John Resig's simple class inheritance](http://ejohn.org/blog/simple-javascript-inheritance/). I'm doing this in Node.js and I'm also using CoffeeScript. I was trying to write CoffeeScript that would output code similar to [this file in the BrowserQuest game](https://github.com/mozilla/BrowserQuest/blob/master/server/js/character.js#L8).

When I write CoffeeScript like this, though:

```
cls = require './class'

module.exports = Model = cls.Class.extend({
  init: () ->
    console.log 'Model.init()'
})
```

The "var" is automatically added to Model, so it doesn't seem to be exported properly.

```
var Model, cls;

cls = require('../class');

module.exports = Model = cls.Class.extend({
  init: function() {
    return console.log('Model.init()');
  }
});
```

Is there a way to mark a variable to not use "var" with CoffeeScript?

Comment: Why not use CoffeeScript's class syntax? Is there anything you need to do that might be stopping you from using that instead?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Every variable is defined with a var on CoffeeScript unless it's given a scope:

```
cls = require './class'

module.exports = GLOBAL.Model = cls.Class.extend({
  init: () ->
    console.log 'Model.init()'
})
```

compiles to:

```
var cls;

cls = require('./class');

module.exports = GLOBAL.Model = cls.Class.extend({
  init: function() {
    return console.log('Model.init()');
  }
});
```

I've used GLOBAL as an example, but you can use any scope.